# Is there a way to load avatar of each user using static method in Django?

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-static

I'm looping through each message which has a particular user which in intern as an image associated with it.

```
<img src="{{message.user.avatar.url}}" />
```

I want to convert it something like this (which I know is obviously very wrong)

```
<img src="{% static {{message.user.avatar.url}} %}" />
```

Is there a way to do so where I can find the equivalent working command of the above code?

Comment: Is it correct that `avatar` is an `ImageField`?

Comment: @IvanStarostin Yes avatar is an ImageField

Comment: Then it is not _static_ but _media_ file. They need different approaches (and storages) and should not be mixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using with

```
{% with avatar_url=message.user.avatar.url %}
<img src="{% static avatar_url %}" />
{% endwith %}
```